# Is it possible to embed c code in an HTML page and if it is, how so?

Tags: html, c

I am a seeking to make a UI for my C school project and I am proficient in HTML CSS Js JQuery.

anybody  know any way that I can 'embed' C in HTML?

Comment: Check out this Q&A at programmer.se: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/53624

Comment: No, but there are other frameworks to make a GUI in C. What platform are we talking about?

Comment: more common to embed html + js in c (eg. in Qt, GTK)

Comment: I am currently on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include or embed C code in an HTML document, but it will not do anything; it will taken just as text data.

There is no support in browsers for using C as client-side scripting language. Theoretically, you could write an interpreter for C (or a subset of C) in JavaScript. Or even a browser that has native C support...

On the more practical side, you can use C as *server-side* programming language. It would then normally be used via CGI (Common Gateway Interface), but then you need support for this on the server you use. And it would not be particularly efficient especially for implementing a UI, since processing any user action would require an HTTP request and would launch a new process on the server, running the compiled C program, which would then send the result back to the browser.

So you probably don’t want to use C in this context. But if you still consider it, check my dusty old page [Getting Started with CGI Programming in C](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can write CGI scripts in any language, including C.

Comment: Some background found on http://www.htmlhelp.com/faq/cgifaq.html - it's an old page, but covers an old technique

Answer (score 1):

You can compile portable C code into web assembly, then embed it into HTML.

A compiler that compiles into web assembly:
https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html

web assembly:
https://webassembly.org/

Comment: If you can provide some code implementation, it would have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `shell_exec()` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <?php shell_exec("python your_file_here.py") ?>
</body>
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace `python your_file_here.py` with `gcc -o example example.c && example`, but i'm not really sure it works...