# I created C game using pipes and ncurses library how could I embed it in a website?

Tags: c, web

I created C game using pipes and ncurses library how could I embed it in a website? I would like that Anyone could play it online

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to embed c code in an HTML page and if it is, how so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995965/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-code-in-an-html-page-and-if-it-is-how-so)

Comment: https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?cpu=riscv64&url=buildroot-riscv64.cfg&mem=256